# ¿Cual de estos modelos relacionales de bases de datos es correct?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

estoy aprendiendo a como diseñar bases de datos y el profesor nos dio un ejercicio sobre el diseño de un diagrama y el ejercicio echo por el profesor es un tanto diferente al mío y no entiendo que cosas no están bien en mi diseño. ¿Por qué el mío no es correcto?. el que tiene fondo blanco es el del profesor y el de fondo negro es el mío.
[image: Imagen del profesor]

[image: Mi diseño]

Comment: El criterio para determinar si tu modelo es correcto o incorrecto comparado con el modelo porpuesto por tu profesor. Aquí sólo vas a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones, incluso algunos van a diferir del modelo presentado por tu profesor. Por otro lado, sin conocer completamente el propósito del ejercicio académico, nada de lo que se te diga aquí será válido para ti y menos para tu profesor. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada por ser basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Pues la verdad es que, en este caso concreto, tampoco es tan opinable: claramente pretendéis asignar a cada usuario unos roles que, a su vez, conceden una serie de permisos. Y con las tablas hay consenso, la discrepancia está en las FK.

- Tu profesor vincula `permisos_x_roles` directamente con `usuarios`, cuando no dispone del campo `usuario_id` en esa tabla.

Eso es un error, lo mires como lo mires. En tu solución te aseguras de que nadie asigne usuarios ni permisos a roles que no existan.

No pasa nada, los profesores también nos equivocamos, coméntaselo y que te lo aclare. Tal vez lo haya hecho así para que aprendáis a detectar ese tipo de fallos.

En el futuro, pásanos el código SQL que genera esa estructura y algún dato de ejemplo para ilustrar con ejemplos los fallos de diseño. Es como mejor se ven.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: también da la sensación de que son lineas superpuestas y el enganche estaría en rol_id de roles. la disposicion de las cajas en la imagen de abajo parece producir conexions mas claras

Comment: Efectivamente aunque, si te fijas, cada línea llega al campo con el que está vinculado y no hay línea que una `permisos_x_roles` con `roles`

Comment: Yo también pienso que hay un tema con las líneas `permisos_x_roles` tiene efectivamente una FK a `roles` y no a `usuarios` como muestra la linea

Comment: ¿En el diagrama de fondo blanco o en el de fondo negro? En el de fondo blanco no veo ninguna línea que llegue a `roles` desde `permisos_x_roles`